# Validation for Model Object using Fluent Validation

Tags: c#

I am using fluentvalidation to validate my object model. I have to make sure that the first two characters of an ISIN must be letters / non numeric. The way I did it is to convert the string to a char array and then perform regex on the first two characters. I was wondering if anyone has a nicer way of doing the validation using a custom fluent validation. Thanks

```
    public class Create
    {
        public class Command : IRequest
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }

            public string Exchange { get; set; }

            public string Ticker { get; set; }

            public string Isin { get; set; }

            public string Website { get; set; }
        }

        public class CommandValidator : AbstractValidator<Command>
        {
            public CommandValidator()
            {
                RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotEmpty();
                RuleFor(x => x.Isin).SetValidator(new MyValidator());
            }
        }

        public class MyValidator : PropertyValidator
        {
            public MyValidator(
                string errorMessage = "Isin. The first two characters of an ISIN must be letters / non numeric.") : base(errorMessage)
            {
            }

            protected override bool IsValid(PropertyValidatorContext context)
            {
                var stringToValidate = context.PropertyValue as String;
                return IsValid(stringToValidate);
            }

            public bool IsValid(string stringToValidate)
            {
                var charString = stringToValidate.ToCharArray();
                if (Regex.IsMatch(charString[0].ToString(), "[0-9]") || Regex.IsMatch(charString[1].ToString(), "[0-9]"))
                {
                    return false;
                }

                return true;
            }

            public class Handler : IRequestHandler<Command>
            {
                private readonly DataContext _context;

                public Handler(DataContext context)
                {
                    _context = context;
                }
                public async Task<Unit> Handle(Command request,
                    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
                {
                    var company = new Company
                    {
                        Name = request.Name,
                        Exchange = request.Exchange,
                        Ticker = request.Ticker,
                        Isin = request.Isin,
                        Website = request.Website
                    };

                    await _context.Companies.AddAsync(company);

                    var success = await _context.SaveChangesAsync() > 0;

                    if (success) return Unit.Value;

                    throw new Exception("Problem saving changes");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> public bool IsValid(string stringToValidate)
> {
>     var charString = stringToValidate.ToCharArray();
>     if (Regex.IsMatch(charString[0].ToString(), "[0-9]") || Regex.IsMatch(charString[1].ToString(), "[0-9]"))
>     {
>         return false;
>     }
>     return true;
> }
> ```

Be aware that each char in a string can be reached by index as `stringToValidate[0]`, so you don't need to call `ToCharArray()`:

```
public bool IsValid(string stringToValidate)
{        
    if (Regex.IsMatch(stringToValidate[0].ToString(), "[0-9]") || Regex.IsMatch(stringToValidate[1].ToString(), "[0-9]"))
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

But `Char` has a static method `Char.IsLetter()` that can be used instead of the `Regex` expression:

```
public bool IsValid(string stringToValidate)
{
     return stringToValidate.Length > 1 && Char.IsLetter(stringToValidate[0]) && Char.IsLetter(stringToValidate[1]);
}
```

This is more consistent with modern unicode character sets, and it will also catch if the two first characters are special chars like `'&'` or `'!'` etc. If you just want to ensure they are not numeric, you can use `Char.IsDigit()` instead.

Comment: @user228313 Just a small addition. As always measure different solutions before you change your current to another one. [In this test](https://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2017/04/24/making-string-validation-faster-no-regular-expressions.html) the ASCII character check outperformed every other solution.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you creating a new variable, and then immediately using it in the `base()` constructor?

```
public MyValidator(
    string errorMessage = "Isin. The first two characters of an ISIN must be letters / non numeric.") : base(errorMessage)
{
}
```

For readability think about moving this directly to `base()` like so:

```
public MyValidator() : base("Isin. The first two characters of an ISIN must be letters / non numeric.")
{
}
```

---

Instead of declaring `stringToValidate` as a string, then using it's value, you could improve conciseness by moving the expression immediately into the function call, like so:

```
protected override bool IsValid(PropertyValidatorContext context)
{
    return IsValid(context.PropertyValue as String);
}
```

---

Instead of the if returning `false` or `true` manually, just return the inverse result of the statement, like this:

```
public bool IsValid(string stringToValidate)
{
    var charString = stringToValidate.ToCharArray();
    return !Regex.IsMatch(charString[0].ToString(), "[0-9]") || Regex.IsMatch(charString[1].ToString(), "[0-9]");
}
```

---

For conciseness, you could rewrite a few lines in the last method (`Handler.Handle()`) like so:

```
public class Handler : IRequestHandler<Command>
{
    private readonly DataContext _context;

    public Handler(DataContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    public async Task<Unit> Handle(Command request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await _context.Companies.AddAsync(new Company
        {
            Name = request.Name,
            Exchange = request.Exchange,
            Ticker = request.Ticker,
            Isin = request.Isin,
            Website = request.Website
        );

        if (await _context.SaveChangesAsync() <= 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Problem saving changes");
        }

        return Unit.Value
    }
}
```

Also, note that I switched the order of the final few lines. You should be checking for false results/exceptions in the indented code, but returning the actual result at the bottom. For more information on reducing nesting, read [this](https://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceNestedConditionalWithGuardClauses.html).